# Customize page number when printing a QTextDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I'm trying to print the content of a `QTextEdit`. For that I'm using `QTextDocument::print(QPrinter*)`. Doing that, a page number is automatically added at the right bottom of the page.

Is there any way to change its format / move it / get rid of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that is hard coded into Qt, so you can't change it.

Have a look at [QTBUG-1688](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-1688). There you see that this fact has already been reported, but they don't seem to work on it. So you will have to do it yourself, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that, there is an way. You can use

`void QTextDocument::drawContents ( QPainter * p, const QRectF & rect = QRectF() )`

Add your desired footer using this.. Obviously it isn't a good one but if you need it for sure, make use of it.

I haven't give a try though. But it should work.